# I am getting strange shadows when using hair cards and cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hair, shadows

I am getting strange shadows when adding view my hair cards in Cycles. I think it occurs when the hair cards are overlapping but im not sure. Anyone knows if there is a fix?[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

I've lined up several transparent planes here as shown.

[image]

You can see that in rendered view we get some shadows on the ground even though these planes shouldn't affect anything.

[image]

This is because the ray cast from the camera hits the Transparency bounce maximum (which is low-ish by default), and reports back that the ray was lost, giving the color black.

Raising the value under Render properties -> Light paths -> Transparency should fix this.

[image]

Comment: Lol this is o funny... I did not see this solution until now when I was searching for help for this exact problem another project. 
This answer was sooo close all this time.
Thank you! this solved everything :D