# black strip on eyelash

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

When I render in cycles I get a black strip that looks like a shadow on my character's eyelashes.
It doesn't happen when I render with eevee.
How can I fix it and remove this shadow from the lower eyelashes?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to increase the maximum of light bounces for transparency? It's in *Cycles > Light Path > Max Bounces > Transparent*. Try something like 16 or 24.

Comment: It Worked. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am getting strange shadows when using hair cards and cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214612/i-am-getting-strange-shadows-when-using-hair-cards-and-cycles)